# API endpoint confusion

Tags: python, django, api, rest

Disclaimer: I am new to working with APIs

I am working on leveraging [gimbals API](https://gimbal.com/doc/rest.html) and am trying to figure out what exactly end points are? I realize that they link to a server, but how exactly are they used in development?

Are the endpoints used to link to specific sources of data?

I am using python(django) and it would be great to understand exactly how access and or change information on gimbals end.

PS- When looking at the gimbal api, I noticed that they have a REST api and some other mobile stuff going on. If I am building a web platform, I would only be interested in the REST API portion correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An endpoint in a RESTful API is generally just a URL.  The URL represents some kind of resource.  If it was an order processing API, the resources would be things like customers, orders, etc.

You interact with these resources by making HTTP requests of various sorts; GET if you want to know the content of a resource, POST if you want to change something, and so on.   [Have a look at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services) for basic information on REST and web APIs.

You don't need Django to interact with a RESTful API that someone else provides.  All you really need is python's urllib, and maybe the json module, if they're sending the data in JSON.  The REST API they provide is probably the main thing they want developers using, but if they have multiple APIs then it's hard to say which one is right for you without understanding the application better.